Getting the Group Key when using group by apply(list)
This is the first time I'm working with Pandas so I'm completely new to this. I was able to group an instance list per account. Now while iterating into that list I would need the account number (group key) to be able to do something with it.
This is an example of the csv file:
enter image description here
#Using Pandas
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(__location__, 'instances.csv'))
df_group = df.groupby('account')['instance-id'].apply(list)
print(df_group.groups.keys())
for account in df_group:
    #Initialize Prettytable
    t = PrettyTable(['Instance ID', 'Instance Name', 'AMI-ID', 'AMI Name'])

    #Initialize the EC2 client to assume role
    sts = boto3.client('sts')
    assume_role = sts.get_caller_identity().get('Arn').split('/')[1]
    assumed_role=sts.assume_role( RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::" + str(account[0]) + ":role/" + assume_role, RoleSessionName= 'Temporary_Session' )

I've read about getting the key using groups.key() but it seems that when it has been already converted to a list is not possible to do it that way as I get the following error when trying.
line 9, in <module> print(df_group.groups.keys())
line 6299, in __getattr__return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'groups'. Did you mean: 'groupby'?

What I'm trying to do at the end is pulling the account number to be able to use sts to assume another role.
Reproducible input:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'account': [
        '111111111111111', '111111111111111', '111111111111111', '111111111111111',
        '111111111111111', '111111111111111', '222222222222222', '222222222222222',
        '222222222222222', '222222222222222', '222222222222222', '222222222222222'
    ],
    'instance-id': [
        'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c4', 'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c4', 'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c4', 'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c7',
        'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c8', 'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c9', 'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c176', 'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c177',
        'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c178', 'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c179', 'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c180', 'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c182'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


Isolate the problem, generate minimal and reproducible example, and provide it as text not image. And provide the results you want with the example you gave. If you need to apply an additional function, again, implement it as a simple function and provide the desired result. If you don't understand, read the following announcement.: [mre]

You should use Series.items:
for group, account in df_group.items():
    print(f'{group=}')
    print(account)

Or, maybe better, don't aggregate and loop over the GroupBy object:
for group, account in df.groupby('account')['instance-id']:
    print(f'{group=}')
    print(list(account))

Output:
group='111111111111111'
['i-124f1c3c401ijk3c4', 'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c4', 'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c4', 'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c7', 'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c8', 'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c9']
group='222222222222222'
['i-124f1c3c401ijk3c176', 'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c177', 'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c178', 'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c179', 'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c180', 'i-124f1c3c401ijk3c182']

